# I want to convert decimal value round up in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

I know this is basic questing but I am unable to convert the value.
Example :
I need roundup values like 0.09 to 9

```
.09 = 9
.01 = 1
.5 = 50
```

I am trying this

```
number_format((float)0.09, 3, '.', '')
```

output is **0.090**

How does Excel convert 0.0988325 into 9.88%?

[Excel Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvNHE.png)

Comment: Why is `0.09=>9` yet `0.5=>50`? There seems no logic to that. Can you define the rules for these operations to transform from a decimal fraction to whole number?

Comment: Multiply by 100?!

Comment: oh there is that then... I'll get my coat

Comment: Why tag `javascript`, when the question explicitly is about "in PHP"?

Comment: then how excel convert 0.0988325 into 9.88% ?

Comment: Multiply by 10000 and then divide by 100

Comment: Using `number_format(0.0988325 * 100, 2)` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Just multiply the number with 100 and append a percentage sign:

### PHP

Use the [`number_format()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) function:

```php
number_format(
  num: $number * 100, 
  decimals: 3, 
  decimal_separator: '.', 
  thousands_separator: ''
) . ' %';
```

*Note that named function arguments require PHP 8.0.0+, if you run on a lower version number, just omit these.*

---

### JavaScript

Use the `toFixed()` method:

```js
const form = document.querySelector("form")
const input = document.querySelector("#number")

form.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  console.log(Number.parseFloat(input.value * 100).toFixed(3) + " %")
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="number" step="any" id="number" required>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```